# Get "class" names of all specific divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whats wrong with my each function? At this way, I get all data, not just the class name:

```
var ClassNames = $("#list .names").each(function() {
   $(this).attr('class');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into `.map()` like this example:

```
var ClassNames = $("#list .names").map(function() {
   return $(this).attr('class');
}).get();
```

You had 2 problems, one being you are not using `return` inside your function. Second even with `return`, `.each` would still return the elements  and not the class'

**Demo**

```js
var ClassNames = $("#list .names").map(function() {
   return $(this).attr('class');
}).get();

console.log(ClassNames)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="names test1"></div>
  <div class="names test2"></div>
  <div class="names test3"></div>
  <div class="names test4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also thx for your support. Interesting way - like it!

Comment: @Pepe No problem, happy to help. Note that your main problem was the missing `return` so it would actually return the class' and not the element itself

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, I just noticed the misleading information in my answer. Fixing it now.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Seemes to be not my day ^^. Big thx!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a list of class names of items please update your code a bit:

```js
var ClassNames = [];
$("#list .names").each(function() {
  ClassNames.push($(this).attr('class'));
});

console.log(ClassNames);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="names list-item"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thx for your support - works fine and I see my fail.

Comment: FYI: this is what jquery (and vanilla) `.map` does without need to initialise an array first (but you do need to add `.get()` to convert to a "proper" array).

Comment: @freedomn-m Good info, thx!